# Getting .python-eggs permission error with mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm getting .python-eggs write permission from this. Could be traced back to mysql import as following.

```
File "/var/www/html/post/db_sql.py", line 7, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as mysql
```

I've found on the internet that setting PYTHON_EGG_CACHE fixes that. But I have no idea where I need to put that? Is it going to be inside db_sql.py? I tried to set os.environ[...] ... with no success.

Please help me out.